# Context free languages belongs to NTIME(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free, time-complexity

As the question states, how do we prove that for every L ∈ L2 (context-free class of languages) is true that L ∈ NTIME(n)?

Can anyone point me to a proof or outline it here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Every context-free language is accepted by a pushdown automaton.

Comment: Ok, we know that NTime[t(n)] = {L | ∃ nondeterministic TM M : L = L(M) and Tm ∈ O(t(n))} and we also know that every pushdown automaton with two stacks is equivalent in power to a Turing machine.

So thats it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There's only one way to tell. Imagine you were grading the assignment, and faced with this answer. Would you give yourself full grades?

Comment: .. is accepted by a "real-time" pushdown automaton.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually in P, the [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) deterministically parses any string of length $n$ in time $O(n^3)$

Comment: And P is a subset of NTIME(n)? That sounds wrong.